# Matrices in equations

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how it is possible to put matrices and determinants inside equations. In particular I would like to know how to generate the following equality:

[image]

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides an environment called `pmatrix` -- short for "matrix surrounded by (round) parentheses", I suppose -- which is perfectly suited for the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
   \lambda & -1 \\
   q & \lambda+p
\end{pmatrix}
=0
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\lambda^2+p\lambda+q=0
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just one part of your formula using the `article` class, it is possible, for example to use, `sansmath` package, within the enviroment,

```
\begin{sansmath} 
....
....
\end{sansmath}
```

Here there is a small example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
This text it is written with the Computer Modern font.
\begin{sansmath} 
\[\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & -1\\
q & \lambda+p
\end{pmatrix}
=0 \iff \lambda^2+p\lambda+q=0
\]
\end{sansmath}
After you have the same initial font.
\end{document}
```

[image]